# "MassTransit.Transport.Send" operation name not found in masstransit 8.0.1.0

Tags: .net, masstransit

I implemented skywalking's  tracking about masstransit through diagnostic events in the previous version, but in v8.0.1.0 I found that the Transport-related OperationName was missing

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit v8 follows the Open Telemetry standard for operation names. There is [even a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsTYClGrOVI) that explains how it is integrated.

Comment: In order to be compatible with the previous code based on DiagnosticSource, I created an ActivityListener and added it to ActivitySource, but I can't get SendHeaders in activity.So I can't add custom "sw8" header.I looked at the source code,there is currently no way to do。

Comment: I think, masstransit needs to add sendcontext to the context of the activity when sending a message

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? @Chris Patterson